# Axios making DELETE and GET in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm working on a small project in vue.js connected to a lumen API (working).

I currently have a list of students ('Etudiants') in which I can click in the list to select one, and delete it via a button in a toolbar.

When a student is deleted I'm reloading the student list (since it's not up to date anymore), therefore I'm doing 2 api calls via axios.

1. **DELETE** http://www.url.com/etudiants (param: idEtudiant)
2. **GET** http://www.url.com/etudiants (param: page)

The problem is that my API calls are not done in **the right order**, as shown here on a screenshot of the calls (with watterfall):

[image: API calls, wrong order]

---

This problem involves 3 vue files.

'*Etudiants.vue*' and its 2 childs: '*ListeEtudiants.vue*' (student list) and '*BarreOutilsEtudiant.vue*' (toolbar)

[image: components and methods]

This simple image shows the hierarchy of the 3 files and the order of which everything **should** execute.

In my case (when it's not working) the action number 3, the axios DELETE, happens in last.

---

Here are the contents of my files:

Etudiants.vue:

```html
<template>
    <div id="etudiants" class="container-fluid h-100">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3 borderR">
                <ListeEtudiants ref="list" @idEtudiantChanged="updateIdEtudiant"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9 bg-light">
                <BarreOutilsEtudiant v-if="idEtudiant != null" :idEtudiant="idEtudiant" @delEtudiant="delEtudiant"/>
                <InfosEtudiant v-if="idEtudiant != null" :idEtudiant="idEtudiant"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    import ListeEtudiants from '@/components/ListeEtudiants.vue'
    import InfosEtudiant from '@/components/InfosEtudiant.vue'
    import BarreOutilsEtudiant from '@/components/BarreOutilsEtudiant.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            ListeEtudiants,
            InfosEtudiant,
            BarreOutilsEtudiant
        },
        data: function(){
            return {
                idEtudiant: null
            }
        },
        methods:{
            updateIdEtudiant(idEtudiant){
                this.idEtudiant=idEtudiant;
            },
            delEtudiant(){
                axios
                    .delete('http://82ab2617.ngrok.io/etudiants', {params: {"idEtudiant" :this.idEtudiant}})
                    .then(this.$refs.list.loadList())
                    .catch(error => console.log(error));
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

ListeEtudiants.vue:

```html
<template>
    <div id="ListeEtudiants">
        <div class="row bg-light">
            <!-- Trigger Modal Ajout Etudiant -->
            <button class="btn btn-light w-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">
                <font-awesome-icon icon="plus" size="1x"/>
                <span> Ajouter un Etudiant</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <ul v-if="etudiants != null" id="list" class="row flex-nowrap list-group list-group-flush pr-0">
            <button v-for="etudiant in etudiants.data" v-on:click='$emit("idEtudiantChanged",etudiant.idEtudiant)' class="btn btn-light text-left list-group-item pl-5 py-1">{{ etudiant.nom }} {{ etudiant.prenom }}</button>
        </ul>
        <ul v-else class="row flex-nowrap list-group list-group-flush pr-0">
        </ul>
        <div class="row bg-light">
            <button class="btn btn-light col-3" v-on:click="page -= 1" :disabled="page === 1 || disabled"><font-awesome-icon icon="chevron-left" size="1x"/></button>
            <div class="align-middle col-6 my-auto">{{ page }} / {{ maxPage }}</div>
            <button class="btn btn-light col-3" v-on:click="page += 1" :disabled="page === maxPage || disabled"><font-awesome-icon icon="chevron-right" size="1x"/></button>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        name: "ListeEtudiants",
        data: function(){
            return {
                etudiants: null,
                maxPage:1,
                disabled:false,
                page:1,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            parseAndDisplay: function(data){
                this.etudiants = data;
                this.maxPage = data.last_page;
                this.page = data.current_page;
                this.disabled = false;
            },
            loadList: function(){
                this.disabled = true;
                this.etudiants = null;
                axios
                    .get('http://82ab2617.ngrok.io/etudiants', {params: {page:this.page}})
                    .then(response =>this.parseAndDisplay(response.data))
                    .catch(error => console.log(error));
            }

        },
        watch: {
            'page': function(newVal, oldVal){
                if((newVal === 0 && oldVal === 1) || (newVal === this.maxPage+1 && oldVal === this.maxPage)){
                    this.page = oldVal;
                }else{
                    if(oldVal !== 0 && oldVal !== this.maxPage+1) {
                        this.loadList();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ,
        mounted() {
            this.loadList();
        }
    }
</script>
```

BarreOutilsEtudiant.vue:

```html
<template>
    <div class="row p-2 navbar-expand navbar-info bg-info">
        <button class="btn btn-info mr-5" type="button"><font-awesome-icon icon="download" size="1x"/> Télécharger le Bulletin</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info ml-auto" type="button"><font-awesome-icon icon="user-edit" size="1x"/></button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger ml-4" v-on:click="$emit('delEtudiant')" type="button"><font-awesome-icon icon="trash-alt" size="1x"/></button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "BarreOutilsEtudiant"
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

---

Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```js
.then(this.$refs.list.loadList())
```

That will call `loadList` immediately and pass the value it returns to `then`, which isn't what you want.

Instead it should be something like this, wrapping it in a function:

```js
.then(() => this.$refs.list.loadList())
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch :) right on. Also, note to @Paul Evans, avoid hardcoding the domain name.

Comment: Thanks you for very much for helping. I'll try asap and come back to you guys! :)

Comment: After trying it, I can tell you it's working like a charm. Thank you very much! @Aanand Kainth, thanks for the tip.